# Does CogroupBy involve only one worker?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a problem I do not understand.

I have two files, one with 272 objects, the second one with 748 922 objects.
I want to add the second collection in the first collection for every objects, so 272*748922...

I need it because every object of the first collection has its own calculation relatively to the second collection.

So I add a key tmp=1 at every record, then I group-by the seconc collection and I merge the value of it (so a vector of 789222 hashmaps) to every record in teh first collection.

The problem is that I have the impression that only one worker is involved.
There is no way to involve more workers on this operation ?

Because I understand it is a big computation but for 50 workers it is nothing...
Especially when you consider the fact that the second collection is 15,7 Mo...

A schema to understand the state :

Pcoll 1 : [{:tmp 1 [more data...] } {:tmp 1 [more data...]} ...] (272 elements)
Pcoll 2 : [{:tmp 1 :data (...a vector of 750 000 elements...)}] (1 element)

Pcoll result : [{:tmp [more data...] :data (vector of 750 000 elements)} ...] (272 elements)

I join by tmp and add :data to every element of Pcoll 1

This is almost nothing in my mind, so why so slow ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, it sounds like all of your elements in both collection have the same key. This means that the result of the `CoGroupByKey` is a single element containing all your data in a single `CoGBKResult`. The processing of a single element cannot be spread across multiple workers because the element cannot be split.

If you use different keys, you would end up with multiple elements, and the processing of each element could end up on a different worker.

Another option that sounds like it may be a better fit for your use case is a [side-input](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs). These allow you to setup the 2nd PCollection as some data that is available to all workers -- either as a single list or as a map -- and then run a lookup against that data while processing each element in `PColl1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is difficult to explain because I use a Clojure wrapper. I join on :tmp so the result is like in SQL : every element of the Pcoll1 contains the content of :data of the unique element of Pcoll2. I just want to add the data of the second Pcoll to all unique elements of Pcoll1. If there is a mean in Java, I would be glad ! I updated my post with a visual result. Under the hood, I know that the Java code for the custom join function first group-by :tmp so it is 1 on 1 operation. I could also  join on 4 fields to spread the work but I have the feeling it will not work ^^

Comment: I think the third paragraph (side-inputs) may be a better fit for the kind of join you're performing. Have you taken a look at those?

Comment: Thanks I interpreted it poorly because I did not know it existed. Hopefully there is this option in the Clojure wrapper. i will test it out and see if it works !

Comment: Hello again, after some holiday I retried it with views and it works amazingly good, thanks a lot. I do the same trick but with side-inputs instead of joining. I got a KV and I use ;getvalue to have my clojure data. It takes 18 minutes instead of at least a day !